# How to close the process properly when running Python Script in Java?

Tags: java

I need to use **Java** to run a **Python Script**.

However, the Python Script cannot be handled as an asynchronous event, because it acts as a proxy, so stays on until i close it.

It works fine when i run it using **Java**, but the script is still running on background after I terminate my code in Eclipse.

So, is there a proper way to close the process when i close my Java application?

**This is how I start my Python Script:**

```
Process p = r.exec("cmd /c python myScript.py");
```

Please let me know if any extra information is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`destroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()) in the process.

```
p.destroy();
```

When to call it?

It depends, it's a command line app? Put it as last line.

It's a gui? A button or the `dispose` method?

Comment: Then call the destroy method where you think it should be closed.

Comment: But where exactly should i put p.destroy() so that when i exit or close the application it will also call p.destroy()??? Is there a listener for closing the application??